# Flutter Game extreme slow

Tags: flutter, performance

Im writing a TokenHunting game.
Im Having problem mixing QRCode reader and Google Maps on the same XamarinForms app then yersterday switched to Flutter, Im completely new to it and just started learning it.
After a lot of research I reach on the result below but it is really slow and with a black screen between screen transitions, Im almost sure that i did something wrong.
Im open to sugestions.

StackOverflow dont allow big block of code then there is a pastebin:

[TokenHunter PASTEBIN source code](https://pastebin.com/raw/uhU4Y0ih)

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:mobile_scanner/mobile_scanner.dart';

class WidgetsProvider {
  
  static StatefulWidget getScreenInstance(AppScreen _appScreen, SharedState _sharedState) {
    StatefulWidget _statefulWidget = ScreenHome(sharedState:_sharedState);
    _sharedState.screen = _appScreen;
    switch (_appScreen) {
      case AppScreen.AgeVerificationScreen: _statefulWidget = ScreenAgeVerification(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Home: _statefulWidget = ScreenHome(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Profile: _statefulWidget = ScreenProfile(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Statement: _statefulWidget = ScreenStatement(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Deposit: _statefulWidget = ScreenDeposit(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Play: _statefulWidget = ScreenPlay(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Login: _statefulWidget = ScreenLogin(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Logout: _statefulWidget = ScreenLogout(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
      case AppScreen.Search: _statefulWidget = ScreenHome(sharedState:_sharedState); break;
    }
    return _statefulWidget;
  }
  
  static Route<dynamic> getRouter(
      BuildContext _context, AppScreen _screenTarget, SharedState _sharedState) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => getScreenInstance(_screenTarget, _sharedState));
  }
  
  static VoidCallback getNavigator(
      BuildContext _context, AppScreen _screenTarget, SharedState _sharedState) {
    _sharedState.navigatingScreen = _screenTarget;
    late VoidCallback vc;
    vc = () {
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          _context,
          WidgetsProvider.getRouter(_context, _screenTarget, _sharedState),
              (route) => false
      );
    };
    return vc;;
  }...........
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old problem with flutter, its since 2019 as you can see here:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39797
As you can see there too they arent to fix it, Xamarin evolved a lot and is
coming the MAUI too, I advise you go back to Xamarin, its impossible to fix it on Flutter.
MAIU is going to a much better alternative and mix barcode scanning with map will be a piece of cake there.